# change the default out type of a class to INT/Number (__repr__ like)

Tags: python, class, ipython

i am trying to work in an interactive environment (CLI)
and wondering if there is a way to change the returned result from a class to be a number format?
do i need additional tools to tweek python like IPYTHON ?? (if so than how)

```
class Register:
    def __init__ (self,name,addr,doc,fields):
        self.name = name
        self.__addr = addr
        self.__doc  = doc
        self.fields = fields
        self._value = 0x0
    #
    def __repr__ (self):
        # self.value = self._value
        return (str(self.value))
    #
    @property
    def value (self):
        return(self._value)
```

...

so when i do:

```
>>> r= Register("r1",0x10,"this description of reg",['f1','f2']
>>> r   # outcome should be the value variable (not in text format)
16
>>> _+10  # so i could do this and get 26
26
```

looking for a way that the `__repr__` or something like it will return a number type INT Float ....

Comment: No, you can't change how the value is returned. If you could, then how would you be able to call methods of the class, since the value would be some other type?

Comment: Apparently what you actually want to know is how to override the `+` operator, not how the class is displayed.

Comment: `_` is `r` itself, not the return value of `r.__repr__`.

Comment: `ipthon` displays the `repr` of what ever object is returned by the operation.  But the object itself is assigned to `_` and the `Out[n]`.  `print(_)` shows the `str` formated string.